# Passing variable in swift with segue

Tags: swift, segue

I'm using segue to open a new window in a xcode app.
The segue is correct, when I tap on the button the new window is shown.
I want to pass a string variable from FirstViewController to DetailViewController but I can't set the variable in the DetailViewController.
This is the code in FirstViewController:

```
if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {

            func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
                        let controller = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
                        controller.Name = "test"
            }

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showdetail", sender: self)
           }
```

And this the DetailViewController code

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var Name: String = ""
     override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      print(Name)
    }
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `prepare(for` must be on the top level of the class.

And please name variables according to the guidelines with starting lowercase letter

```
func someMethod()
{
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "showdetail", sender: self)
    }
}

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   let controller = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
       controller.name = "test"
   }
}
```